# does not change the locale with using LocaleAction

Tags: struts, struts-1

i use struts 1.3 and want to make localization.
that's what I'm doing:

1. in struts-config.xml:

   ```
   <form-bean name="English" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
       <form-property name="language" type="String" initial="en" />
   </form-bean>
   <form-bean name="Russian" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
       <form-property name="language" type="String" initial="ru" />
   </form-bean>

   <action-mappings>
       <action path="/English" name="English"
           type="org.apache.struts.actions.LocaleAction">
       <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" />
   </action>
   <action path="/Russian" name="Russian"
           type="org.apache.struts.actions.LocaleAction">
       <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" />
   </action>
   ```

   ```
   <controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor" />
   ```
2. on jsp.page

   ```
   <html:link action="/Russian">
       <bean:message key="jsp.header.russian"/>
   </html:link>
   <html:link action="/English">
           <bean:message key="jsp.header.english"/>
   </html:link>
   ```

maybe i do something wrong? any ideas?
P.S. yes, i have messages_ru.properties and messages_en.properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found the reason, struts do not know of this type as a String.

```
<form-property name="language" type="java.lang.String" initial="en" />
```